# Fetch by date component in Realm Swift

Tags: swift, date, realm

I have a Realm class that stores some data readings and the date on which the reading the was recorded. The structure of the class is like so:

```
class MyObj: Object {
    dynamic var reading: Int = 0
    dynamic var dateTime: Date = Date()
}
```

Now I want to query realm for all readings corresponding to a particular hour, such that I can group them like so: all readings corresponding to a particular hour regardless of the date should be summed up. So if I have data readings for five days, the end results would be 24 values, each corresponding to the hour of day summed up for the five days.

One solution I have right now is to add another field for hour in my Realm class and then fetch all objects corresponding to a particular hour. I want to know if this is possible with realm queries? I have searched allot and have not found an inbuilt solution. Am I missing something?

Comment: do you want to get all objects in same hour ?

Comment: yes. all entries for a particular hour in all days

Comment: The problem is unclear; if you know the start and end date, Realm can query for all dates within that range. Once you have the Date objects you can iterate over them to get the date components, hh mm and ss, which will then enable you to store and sum readings for each hour. Are you asking how to query Realm for a date range? How to iterate over the results or how to get date components from a date object.. or something else?

Comment: Say I have hourly readings for 5 days in my db and I want to query objects for a certain hour only (say 2pm, regardless of what date they are) without fetching all the hourly objects (eg 1pm, 3pm, 4pm, .. etc). I can do all above you mentioned, but I wonder if I can query realm directly for an hour predicate or something similar